# hibernate fetch lazy: Initialize() or HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, fetch, lazy-initialization

Today I learned one tutorial where author explained hibernate association one-to-many / many-to-one.
I don't want to write all his code here. So, I try to focus on main...

We have two entities: "**Team**" and "**Player**"

In code we have:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="team_id")
private Team team;
```

and

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Player> players;
```

The main thing which I interested is type of fetch. So, we inserted one *team* and some *players* which are belongs to this *team*. 
My DAO class marked with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
```

And now I want to load *team* entity from database with filled collection of *players*.

```
Team team = new Team();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(team, id);

//and after somewhere in code
team.getPlayers();
```

At result I will get `LazyInitializationException`. It's obviously...

We can resolve this problem:

```
Hibernate.initialize(team.getPlayers());
```

Or we can can load collection of players using HQL. I mean:

```
Query query = currentSession().createQuery("from Player p where p.team.id =:id");
query.setParameter("id",key);

team.setPlayers(new HashSet(query.list()));
```

Is it right solutions? And which of them I should use in real development?

And one more question. After I initialized collection of players (no matter which of solutions I used) I can get one of them. Ok, And in "player" entity field Team will initialize. Why? And this *team* will be with filled player's collection... we have circular dependencies... This is normal?

Comment: did you close Hibernate session after `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(team, id);` line? is session still alive ?

Comment: I use Spring and I hope that Spring framework will take care of closing the session. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: i dont know what kind of spring configuration you used. but as per my understading befor `team.getPlayers();`  call, session might have get closed and team object got detached from session. That might be the reason for this error.  If you try to lazy load from detached object then you will get this kind of error.

Comment: **Anchit Pancholi** thanks. You are right. Session might have get closed after `get(team, id)`. And after  when i call `team.getPlayers()` I get LazyInitializationException becouse i set `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` not `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. I don't argue with this fact. It is normal... I asked about initialization of player's collection by hand: using method initialize() or HQL. Which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LazyInitializationException comes when session is closed and you try to load lazy object from detached Object. Here team is detached  object (As session might have closed before this call) and trying to load lazy object players.

And About which approach need to use for this kind of problem, it is up to your requirement. if you call Hibernate.initialize on each proxy, Each call will generate one query.

And with below you are using joint :-

`Query query = currentSession().createQuery("from Player p where p.team.id =:id");`

this will only require one query, i think you should use this approach if you query a lots of data.

For more information take  a look at [this link](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch02s02.html).